# Counting Spaces of Intersecting

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I can't wrap my head around this one.

Let $W$ be an $N$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $V$ an $l$-dimensional subspace of $W$. Now I want to count the number of subspaces U of dimension $l$ such that $\dim (U\cap V)=l-i$ for a given $i$.

It is clear that I can choose the $(l-i)$-subspace of intersection in $\text{gbc}(l,l-i)=\text{gbc}(l,i)$ ways, where $\text{gbc}$ represents the Gaussian Binomial Coefficient.

After having chosen a $(l-i)$-subspace of intersection I have to complete this space so I will have dimension $l$. I can do this by first adding one of the $q^N-q^l$ vectors in $W$ not already in my $(l-i)$-subspace or $V$. I have however to take into account that some vectors span the same $(l-i+1)$-subspace. Apparently there are $q^l-q^{l-i}$ such vectors. Continuing this process there is

$$\frac{(q^N-q^l)(q^N-q^{l+1})\dots (q^N-q^{l+i-1})}{(q^l-q^{l-i})(q^l-q^{l-i+1})\cdots (q^l - q^{l-1})}$$
ways of completing my $(l-i)$ subspace.

I don't know why there is $q^l -q^{l-i}$ vectors that span the same subspace. Can anyone explain this? I know that $q^l-q^i$ is the number of vectors missing from my subspace but I'm not really sure what to use this for.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $U$ and $V$, the denominator counts the number of sequences $(v_1,\ldots,v_i)$ which, taken (as a set) together with a basis for $U\cap V$, form a basis for $V$.  There are $q^l-q^{l-i}$ choices for $v_1$, $q^l-q^{l-i+1}$ choices for $v_2$, etc.

I think a natural way to think about this problem is to start with the analogous problem for subsets. Suppose you have an $N$-element set $W$, and an $l$-element set $V$ contained in it.  You want to count the number of $l$-element sets $U \subset W$ such that $|U\cap V|=l-i$.  The set $U$ decomposes as $l-i$ elements from $V$ together with $i$ elements from $W\setminus V$, and these two collections can be chosen independently.
So the answer is
$$\binom{l}{l-i}\binom{N-l}{i} = \binom{l}{l-i}\binom{N-l}{i}.$$

For your problem we have a similar setup.  We have a decomposition $U\approx (U\cap V) \oplus U/(U\cap V)$.  There are $\binom{l}{l-i}_q$ ways to select $U\cap V$ as a subspace of $V$.  The second term $U/(U\cap V)=U/V$ is [isomorphic to] an $i$-dimensional subspace of $W/V$, and there are $\binom{N-l}{i}_q$ ways to choose this subspace.  So the final count is
$$\binom{l}{l-i}_q\binom{N-l}{i}_q = \binom{l}{l-i}_q\binom{N-l}{i}_q.$$

Comment: I thought this was taken care of by only choosing the $q^N-q^l$ vectors not spanned by $V$ or $U$?

Comment: in your final count you are missing pieces. You have to multiply everything by $q^{i^2}$. First of all $U/(U\cap V)\cong (U+V)/V$. Moreover different $U$ give the same subspace $(U+V)/V$. Your correspondance is not bijective.

Comment: what is $\binom{a}{b}_q$? And how does it connect to the number given by the OP? And you gave same terms on both sides of the two equalities. Did you mean some other way to compute?